# Share ARSCNView on multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, arkit

I want to build an app where users can swipe between different AR views filled with different content, **but in the same AR session** - so they don't need to search for plane/feature every time.

I've tried to pass ARSCNView from one ViewController to another via a singleton. But it gives me error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key sceneView.'
```

Whats the right pattern to use in this case?

MainViewController:

```
extension MainViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate 
{
    func initAR(){
        ArSceneView.delegate = self
        ArSceneView.scene = scene
        ArSceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
        MainViewController.manager.ArSession=ArSceneView
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        ArSceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

}
```

AnotherViewController:

```
class AnotherViewController:  {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        MainViewController.manager.ArSession.delegate = self
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: I've found a workaround - if you want to use same AR session on different ViewControllers, feel free to use UIPageViewController, and SCNView to it, and then it's persistent across different Views connected to UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is interesting in itself. So i tried out simple passing of scenview, session from one to next viewcontroller in prepareForSeague. It switched without any error but sceneview was empty. Now i am not sure if it reset or completely new session started. I would really like to know if yours work.

For your problem - if you dont have any other specific functions in your AnotherViewController, you can swipe between contents instead.

Comment: I have also different ui elements on it, so just swiping through content won't work. Will do some more tests with i.e. uipageviewcontroller and if it's gonna work - I'll post here an update.